# What is the absolute import and relative import for this kind of directory structure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror, relative-import

I have a directory structure like this,

Assignments

├── Assignment1

│       ├── Assignment-1.pdf

│       └── assignment1.py

└── Methods

├── **init**.py

├── primality.py

I want to import functions from the **primality.py** file into the **assignment1.py** file.

What is my relative and absolute import line for this dirctory structure?

I also tried using this, `from ..Methods.primality import func`

but it gives me an error,

`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Can anyone explain me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How did you run which file to get that ImportError?

Comment: There are multiple assignments folders which contains assignment.py file and every assignment.py required different custom packages from the directory Methods. So, in assignment.py file, I import custom packages from the Methods directory with this line "from ..Methods.primality import func" but it resulted into the import error mentioned in the question.

Comment: Yes I asked how do you run this code - what is the command line (for one of the assignments)

Comment: I ran `$ python3 assignment1.py`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score 0):

You should add the missing `__init__.py` as in:

```
├── Assignment1

│       ├── Assignment-1.pdf

│       ├── __init__.py # this

│       └── assignment1.py

└── Methods

│       ├── __init__.py

│       ├── primality.py
```

then go to the `Assignments` folder and from there run:

```
$ python3 -m Assignment1.assignment1 # note no py
```

Then python sees the directory structure as a *package* structure and Methods/Assignment1 are packages (and you should rename them to methods/assignment1)